# How to programmatically purge/clean cocoa application memory?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, instruments, autorelease

I'm working on a Mac app. Initially monitoring Xcode's memory report while I ran my app showed showed the memory was just ramping up crazy. I used Instruments and profiled my app for allocations and leaks. Turned out there wasn't much leaked memory as you would expect due to strong reference cycles etc. However there was a lot of abandoned memory. By following the stack trace that lead to my code I have fixed by 70% using autorelease pools etc. Still the remaining 30% of abandoned memory seems to point system calls.

Now I have two questions based on that I have two questions

1) I want to fix the remaining 30%. How can I get rid of abandoned memory? I have already used Instruments and know exactly where those system calls are spawned but still dont know what to do to have that memory be cleaned up. (using ARC no manual retain/ release and autorelease doesn't seem to make a diff.)

2) After I know whatever my application was doing has completed and there is no need for any memory to be there (just like the application first started) I want to get rid of all memory that my app has used up. This I plan to use as a brute force approach to clean up all memory just like the system would if the user closes the app or turns off the system.
Basically if I know where my apps memory is in the file system I'll just programmatically call purge command on that or something similar. Because at this point I'm 100% sure nothing needs to be in memory for the app except for the first screen that you would expect the first time you launch the app.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477228/how-to-clean-ram-programmatically-cocoa), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277492/programmatically-free-up-system-memory-using-objective-c), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099200/cant-locate-abandoned-memory-in-ios-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580883/how-to-clear-abandoned-memory-that-doesnt-point-to-own-code) but they weren't helpful.

Comment: As a phrase, "apps memory is in the file system" doesn't really make much sense.  Do you have a couple of specific example of memory that's being held by the system...they might lead to some clues?

Comment: @PhillipMills I basically want to know where the RAM is stored, is it /usr/bin? where does the app heap memory reside? ( as in Xcode stores them in derived data folder) and then how can I purge it?

Comment: You're confusing dynamic memory (RAM) with persistent storage (disk, SSD, ...).  They are two physically separate things inside your computer.  Some systems make process memory look as if it's part of the file system or make disk space behave as if it were part of RAM but, from an application's point of view, that's smoke and mirrors.

Comment: @PhillipMills True, but OS uses memory swapping and start using disk memory to if its running low on RAM. even though this allows app to run it will slow performance . My question is how do I manually do what the system does? (sorry if I'm being weird here, this isn't a question of mine, it's for someone else who isn't good with English and using SO, I don't do much of objc & Mac development, just iOS and Swift)

Comment: Can you post some of the code that is leading to your abandoned memory? It's not really valid to purge random app memory by brute force in the hopes of cleaning something up, but perhaps we can help diagnose some specific problems and offer approaches to fix them.

Comment: @Honey The practical answer is, you don't.  What you do instead is track down the things that are causing memory to be held and fix them.